# there are different categories for a column in the dataframe and want to merge/rename these different columns into 3 categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are different categories for  a column in the dataframe  and want to merge/rename these different columns into  3 categories and this column is object data type.I have tried using below code.. i..e using map function and also  tried converting the object data type into categorical but
i dont see the expected result and also see a value like when i query the unique  values for that column.

Code: Tried different codes to acheive the below 3 categories

```
Happiest, Unhappy, Neutral

df['Status'].dtype = object

df['Status'] = df['Status'].rename({'Happy':'Happiest','Smile':'Happiest','Sad':'Un happy','ok':'Neutral'},
                                   inplace=True)
```

Or

Converted to categorical

```
df2['Status'] = df2['Status'].astype('category')

df['Status'] = df['Status'].cat.rename_categories({'Happy':'Happiest','Smile':'Happiest','Sad':'Un happy','ok':'Neutral'})
```

Or

```
df['Status'] = df['Status'].map({'Happy':'Happiest','Smile':'Happiest','Sad':'Un happy','ok':'Neutral'},
                 inplace=True)
```

The output of all the above tried codes are nan, happiest, Neutral or completely nan.

Comment: If you are using inplace=True then the Method returns None. Try to remove the inplace keyword or the assigment.
If this din't fix your Problem, can you provide a smal code example?

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example if removing `inplace=True` does not solve your issue

Comment: I tried without inplace=True but the output has no changes i..e no error and no change in the o/p .................df['Status'] = df['Status'].rename({'Happy':'Happiest','Smile':'Happiest','Sad':'Un happy','ok':'Neutral'})    here the o/ when i did print(df2['Status'].unique()) : i get as 'happy','Smile','Sad' .. No change in the output.

Comment: The above are the codes that i have tried

Comment: figured out, used replace function and is working now..